# Print the bound prepare statement using sqlite libraryinc

Tags: c, sqlite, prepared-statement

Here is a sqlite library problem  (using C)

After binding parameters of a prepared statement, how can I print the SQL with the bound parameters for debugging?

I google it and only find a function to print the original prepare statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the prepared statement after the `bind()`. For debug-purposes, you can sprintf the values into the sql-string and give that to `prepare()` thus omitting the bind-calls.

What is your original sql string and what are your bind-calls?